# Streaming logs from SpringApps to Azure Portal/Consokle

Tags: spring, azure, azure-log-analytics

Is there a simple way of streaming live logs from Azure Spring Apps to Azure Portal?

Console `az spring app logs ...` works fine, but I would like to get live logs into Portal/UI. I know I can add log analytics + stream to it, then use `Logs`, but it is not really a live stream.

Any thoughts? Or is the `az-cli` log streaming - the only available option?

Thanks.